# In Civ 5, do buildings get any penalties when you lose a source of needed strategic resource?

Tags: civilization-5

The units get combat penalties when you lose a required strategic resource, but what about buildings like factories, which require coal, power plants and other? Do they also get a production penalty if you go negative on resource?

Comment: This question could be expanded to include the other buildings that require resources - hydro plants (aluminum), spaceship factories (aluminum) and nuclear plants (uranium).

Comment: @Oak, good idea!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those buildings continue to work normally, I just tried it. The factory and the hydro plant worked like they should even with negative coal and aluminum.

Comment: When in doubt, try it out :P

Comment: great, so after they are built they probably can just use natural gas and titanium respectively :)